# webview in tableview is not getting displayed in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

In iOS 7, webview in tableview is not getting displayed where as it works fine in iOS 5.In iOS 7 ,created a sample application which contains webview in tableview .It works fine. After searching for a long time I found that may be due to gesture recognizers, Webview in tableview is not getting displayed. I tested this scenario in my sample application. But it  works fine. So no problem with gesture recognizers.

Any idea why webview in tableview is not getting displayed in iOS 7?

This is the code to check:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return [app.resultsDic count];

}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",section];    

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   

   return 1;


}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 150;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UIWebView *webView ;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;


    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath section];

    if ( [app.resultsDic count]>0 )
    {
        NSArray *cellSubviews = [cell subviews];
        for (UIView *currSubView in cellSubviews) {
            [currSubView removeFromSuperview];
        }
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 8, 280, 140)];
        webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.jpg"]];

        [cell addSubview:webView];

        //Retrieving Data into Dictionary and formatting the data using htmlString

        NSDictionary *resDict = [app.resultsDic valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",row]];

        NSMutableString *htmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        NSString *initialString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<table>"];
        NSString *endString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"</table>"];
        [htmlString appendString:initialString];
        for (int e = 0 ; e < [[resDict allKeys] count]; e++) {
            NSString *currentKey = [[resDict allKeys] objectAtIndex: e];


            [htmlString appendFormat:@"<tr><td ><b>%@</b></td><td>:</td><td><font color=DarkBlue>%@</font></td></tr>", currentKey,[resDict objectForKey:currentKey]];

        }
        [htmlString appendString:endString];
        NSString *cssString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"table { width:100%; font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana}"];

        NSString *htmlString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <head>     <style type=\"text/css\"> %@ </style> </head> <body> %@ </body> </html>", cssString, htmlString];  

        [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString1 baseURL:nil];

        [webView.scrollView setBounces:NO];

    }
        return cell;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: webview in table view in the sense you are loading web view in each cells right?

Comment: update your question with your exact code.

Comment: Other then IOS 7 in all other version , is contentloading in all the web page?

Comment: Yes other than IOS 7 ,content loading in all the webpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    I resolved this issue in iOS 7.

  //In ios 5, I have added this code for removing the subviews in webview.

      NSArray *cellSubviews = [cell subviews];

            for (UIView *currSubView in cellSubviews) 
            {
                [currSubView removeFromSuperview];
            }

    //In ios 7 , I have removed the above code. Because we need not to write any code for removing the subviews in webview.
```

Answer (score 0):

this simple code works for me in iOS7

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIWebView *web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    [web loadHTMLString:@"im a <b>webview</b>" baseURL:nil];
    web.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:web];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try replacing the following code

```
    NSString *htmlString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <head>     <style type=\"text/css\"> %@ </style> </head> <body> %@ </body> </html>", cssString, htmlString];
```

to

```
    NSString *htmlString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <head>     <style> %@ </style> </head> <body> %@ </body> </html>", cssString, htmlString];
```